# Android app having nullpointerexception when started by uri

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have a Uri scheme which is pretty standard. My manifest is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.enayet.minigma"
    android:versionCode="11"
    android:versionName="1.5.1" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".multiscreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:path="minigma"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
        </activity>

    </application>

    <uses-sdk
        android:maxSdkVersion="19"
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

</manifest>
```

and in my main activity (this is the activity I want the Uri to go to with the information I parse from the Uri) I have a getIntent() in the OnCreate function. The problem is, even though I have an if statement which guards against this, Android gives me the following error:  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.enayet.minigma/com.enayet.minigma.multiscreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException

This is my OnCreate function:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_multiscreen);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Uri data = intent.getData();
        if (data != null) {
            List<String> params = data.getPathSegments();
            String message = params.get(0);
            EditText msg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageEdit);
            if (message != null) msg.setText(message);
        }
  if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which line does it say the null pointer is happening on?

Comment: Just a guess because I can't see which line the exception is happening on but maybe your msg object is null.

Comment: Your stacktrace should indicate which line exactly is causing the NullPointer exception. Could be your params is null so when you call params.get(0) that would throw a NullPointer.

Comment: the null pointer is on this line: "if (message != null) msg.setText(message);". You guys are probably correct in saying msg is null, but how can I guard against that?